# Issue with Express.js: CSS and JS files not loading from the 'public' folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, web

I'm currently working on a web project using Express.js, and I'm facing issues with loading CSS and JavaScript files from the 'public' folder. I've followed the common practices, but it seems something is not working correctly. Here's the structure of my project:

- **`public`**

  - **`style.css`**
  - **`script.js`**
- **`views`**

  - **`index.ejs`**
  - **`AboutMe.ejs`**
  - **`ContactMe.ejs`**
- Other Express.js files (**`app.js`**, **`routes`**, etc.)

In my EJS templates, I'm linking to my CSS and JavaScript files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style.css">
<script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
```

But my styles and scripts are not being applied to my pages as expected. I've verified the file paths, and everything seems correct.

Is there something specific I need to configure in my Express.js application to make sure the files in the 'public' folder are served correctly? I've tried various approaches and searched for similar issues but haven't found a solution yet.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information about my project setup or configuration, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help!

What I've Tried:

I've double-checked the file paths and the file location of my style.css.
I've ensured that I'm using the correct path in my EJS templates.
I've checked that the express.static middleware is correctly configured.

**What I Expect:** I expect the CSS styles to be applied to my EJS templates when I load my Express.js app

Comment: You keep saying that you've checked things and that they are correct, but you haven't provided a [mcve] so we can't tell if you're right or not.

Comment: You don't have a  `styles` folder in your tree.  Use `/public/style.css`.  same with `/scripts`...

Comment: @JeremyFiel — It's how the `static` module is configured which determines if those URLs work or not. There's no need for `public` to appear in the URL.

Comment: So, Express serves NO files at all by default.  So, the only way that it will serve your CSS and JS files is if you have a route (usually using `express.static()`) that will serve them when requested.  Then, on top of that, the URL you specify for the resource in the web page much match exactly how your `express.static()` route and path are defined relative to where the files live in your server file system.

Comment: Im addition, your URLs tell the server to look in `/styles/style.css`, but there is no directory on your server with that name that `express.static()` could find it in.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use the [static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express) to serve static files at fixed paths.

Given both your CSS and JS files are in the same folder but you want to serve them via separate `styles` and `scripts` paths, you should be able to use something like this...

```js
app.use(["/scripts", "/styles"], express.static("public"));
```

Using this, any of the following URLs should work

- /styles/style.css
- /styles/script.js
- /scripts/style.css
- /scripts/script.js

This may not be what you actually want though. A more common practice is to place static assets in their own sub-directories and serve the entire *public* directory statically

```
.
└── public
    ├── scripts
    │   └── script.js
    └── styles
        └── style.css
```

```js
app.use(express.static("public"))
```